# Run async function on background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm working on a project that includes a server and a client.
The client sends every second a UDP packet to the server, and according to the server's response it might open a TCP connection with the server (and recieve files from the server), the client's program has a GUI which I don't want to block (made in WPF MVVM), and also it's problematic to start async function on constructor of the MainWindow as constructors can't be async.
So my question is, can I and should I run async functions on a background thread? Does the async improve performance if it's on a background thread, I'm talking about the difference between these options:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DirectoryViewModel DirectoryVM = new DirectoryViewModel();
    this.DataContext = DirectoryVM;
    DirectoryVM.StartListen(); //Unwanted as constructor won't finish
}
```

To

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DirectoryViewModel DirectoryVM = new DirectoryViewModel();
    this.DataContext = DirectoryVM;
    Task.Run(DirectoryVM.StartListen()); //Possible but async might be faster
}
```

To

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DirectoryViewModel DirectoryVM = new DirectoryViewModel();
    this.DataContext = DirectoryVM;
    Task.Run(async () => await DirectoryVM.StartListenAsync()); //Is it faster than the second option?
}
```

From what I've seen I shouldn't run async code on background thread like this, but why? Isn't it faster than running sync code on a background thread? 
Also I guess it's not really different but on my server I'll create a constant running thread that listens for tcp connections and will send files over it, should I make the send file function async or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you starting the background thread? I can only see a `Task.Run`.

Comment: Meant generally a seperate thread, sorry for my miss understanding. Doesn' Task.Run queue to threadpool?

Comment: The 3rd option only *seems* faster because you are not waiting for it to complete.  When `MainWindow` exits, `DirectoryVM.StartListenAsync` may not be complete, and worse yet, you have no way of knowing when it has *actually* completed.

Comment: It's also an [*incredibly* bad](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) idea to run async code in a constructor.

Comment: The thing is the function never ends, it basically sends a datagram, waits a second and sends another, untill the server returns true and then the function opens a tcp connection and accepts files and then goes back to send datagrams each second. And I didn't check which is faster, I don't really have the implementation, it's more of a conceptual question about is it ok to start async method on a seperate thread (be it threadpool or anything else). Cause in this case I think I have to run this code on a seperate thread

Comment: `Task.Run` indeed schedules to the `ThreadPool`, but the assigned thread will have very little work to do unless *starting* the task is CPU-intensive. Normally it isn't. Starting most tasks is usually cheap, and awaiting them to complete is even cheaper, because normally [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) is required for the completion of a `Task`.

Comment: For a good answer we would have to know what `StartListen[Async]()` does. But it looks like the first snippet will do. What kind of performance differences do you expect here?  It will be nanoseconds.

Comment: This code is more of an anacdote, I want my client to constantly send udp messages to my server and according to the servers answer either wait a second and send another message or open a tcp socket to recieve files, so the startListen func never quits, it's always running, so as I don't want to block the UI, I think I should run the code on another thread. I basically want to understand if I should run an async func (that does all the socket communication async) on another thread, how to do it, and if I shouldn't then why not, why won't it improve the performance of the seperate thread?

Comment: `async` really isn't a great choice for something this is going to always run in a loop and never exit.  A real, dedicated, thread is a much better match functionally.

Comment: Alright, so are you saying the second option is best? (or did you mean to create a thread instead of using threadpool? If so then why?  And also, I still don't understand why not combine the two, won't it be more efficient to have the thread run async function instead of sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I've seen I shouldn't run async code on background thread like this, but why?

I'm not aware of any recommendations not to run asynchronous code with `Task.Run`.

`Task.Run` should be avoided on ASP.NET (for both synchronous and asynchronous code), but that doesn't apply here since you have a GUI app.

> Isn't it faster than running sync code on a background thread?

No. The code will not be any faster. `async` is about freeing up threads, not running faster.

I think the concern that you've seen is that of ignoring tasks. Using `Task.Run` and ignoring the task it returns is problematic because that's a form of fire-and-forget. So if your loop fails due to an exception, your application would never know. One way around this is to `await` the task from an `async void` method. For example, as your Window's `Initialized` event handler:

```
async void Window_Initialized(object, EventArgs)
{
  await Task.Run(DirectoryVM.StartListen);
  // or, if asynchronous:
  await DirectoryVM.StartListenAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
About running async code on a background thread - I tried to find information and couldn't find much and in the same time as you said I got mixed up with the concerns about ignoring the task, only today was it that I saw your answer to a question, that said when sending an async func to Task.Run, the Task.Run knows to await it so I don't have to add the async lambda, did I understand it correctly?
About the client code - someone told me about the timer class, so I just have to subscribe to the event of tick and set it to second and run the handle function.

Comment: And an additional question - if I should not ignore that task returned by Task.Run, what should I do in my server's code, where I to always listen for udp messages, and meanwhile listen for tcp connections and for each tcp connection send/receive files (By the way the server is a console app, not a GUI one, atleast for now)?
And just to make sure I understood it correctly - Async is about not blocking threads, so in the UI thread it is beneficial in order to not block the UI, and in thread pool so the thread can handle other things instead of waiting?

Comment: `Task.Run` doesn't need a separate lambda; it takes a delegate so you can pass it a method directly. I interpreted your question as being about the client side; to avoid ignoring tasks, your code should eventually `await` the task; this may be done in an `async void` method if necessary. Your understanding of the benefits for client vs server is correct.

Comment: And what if I don't want to await it? Right after calling the method I want to do other things (In the case I'm talking about I need to go back to listening), what should I do? I can either ignore the task (And in my case I don't think I care too much if it had an exception), or I could save the task but don't await it, add it to a list, and whenever its status is RanToCompletion, remove it from the list, if its faulted handle the exception. Is that a good idea?

Comment: You could do the list thing. Or like I recommended, `await` the task within an `async void` method wrapper.

Comment: Sorry for asking many questions, but I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by that: Do you mean in the function that I don't want to be blocked I should call an async void method that calls the Async Task method instead of calling it directly, and then when the wrapper method will reach the await it will return to the listening function and so the listening function will continue running while the wrapper one will wait for the Task (and then handle exceptions if needed)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. If an exception does happen, the `async void` treats it as though it were a top-level exception, so it won't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> ... is it ok to start async method on a seperate thread ...

I think you fundamentally misunderstand the async methods. Calling an async method does not create a new thread or offload the entire method onto any other thread. Calling an async method is like calling any other method, but it **maybe** at some point returns execution back to the caller (with a Task as a promise) and finishes its remaining job at some point.

Though it is possible to spin up an always running periodic listener using async method, it is rather against its purpose.

When you call an async method, you expect it will be run to completion within a reasonable time (hence why you want to await on it), but it might takes long enough time to do something else meanwhile. In your case, you should explicitly start a new background task or thread what does the periodic check for you. It can be a new thread or better, a new task (Task.Run for example).

> From what I've seen I shouldn't run async code on background thread
>   like this, but why?

According to your comments the `DirectoryVM.StartListen()` starts the constantly running listening, what does not have to be async. Unless it does any async calls, it is not something awaitable.

> Isn't it faster than running sync code on a background thread?

Async is not about speed, but about thread blocking. It does not matter if the thread is foreground or background, using async method for an I/O operation, like calling an http endpoint or sending a UDP packet is always beneficial, if the thread can do other things while waiting, or otherwise blocking that thread might cause other issues.

> Also I guess it's not really different but on my server I'll create a
>   constant running thread that listens for tcp connections and will send
>   files over it, should I make the send file function async or not?

You should, if it is beneficial. See previous part.

Comment: I am not sure that I agree that a periodic operation inside an async method should be avoided. I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: If I call an async method I don't expect it has the lifetime of the application's

Let's say you have the following method:
`async Task DoForever()
{
    while(true)
    {
        await SomeCall();
        await Task.Delay(X);
    }
}`
Now, if you know how this method works you can just call `DoForever()` but calling `await DoForever()` will block the execution. I think this kind of forever running async methods should be avoided.

Comment: The `DoForever` method (or better `DoForeverAsync`), as it stands now would return a fire-and-forget task that should not be awaited. It should be very unsurprising that awaiting this task blocks forever. Imagine someone writing `await Task.Delay(-1)`, and then be surprised that the next line of code is never reached. This person needs urgently some coffee! A possibly better design would be to accept a `CancellationToken` parameter, and then at the app's finalizer to cancel the token and `await` the task, to keep things tidy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Just to make sure, it is beneficial for me to send the files async on the tcp thread, because it will free the thread to handle other things while waiting for the tcp send to finish, correct?
And also, async/await isn't making my code run faster (unless it's async parallel I guess), but it is beneficial in order not to block threads so it does help in some way to effeciency, right?